# How to place images inside image in grid?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need to place images side by side and need to place one small image icon below the each image.please help me how to design ?any samples please let me know..

How to place userimage inside one small image dynamically based on condition..please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show images like this in windows phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946553/how-to-show-images-like-this-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: PLEASE don't just keep adding question that are the same as previous ones. If you want to add more info, please update the original question instead of creating a whole new question - that doesn't help anybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made simple prototype for you. I can't make whole screen for you. Here are the basic things as I got from your comments and screenshot. Please see XAML and screenshot below:

```
 <ListBox Name="lstImages" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,-15" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel>
                        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Height="100" Width="110" Source="{Binding BigImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="{Binding SmallImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-35,10,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: If you can see in this screenshot i added little icon of search on each image. You can better see this icon on blue one screen. I was short of small icon so I used this one but its not much clear as its png. :)

Comment: Thanks @Arslan.Can you tell me how do you set the margin for small image?

Comment: I placed all controls in stack panel and as small image in bottom. I am giving margin from Right and bottom to gain required shape. Please look into the silverlight controls. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>   
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Image Source="Your image" Grid.Row="0"/>
       <Image Source="Your small icon" Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>

<Grid Grid.Column="1">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Image Source="Your image" Grid.Row="0"/>
   <Image Source="Your small icon" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Any samples  please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="Firstimage" />
      <Image Source="Secondimage" />
    </Stackpanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="Firsticon" />
      <Image Source="Secondicon" />
    </Stackpanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But here you have to make some changes to the icon stackpanel like setting some margin, inorder to make it aligned to the actual images.

This is just an alternative, you can also use Grid's as answered by nucleons

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your images in listbox then wrap this way in wrap panel and you can set direction of wrappanel as well. Wrappanel is found in silverlight toolkit of windows phone 7.

```
                         <ListBox Name="lstImages">
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-15" />
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <toolkit:WrapPanel>
                                        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                  <stackpanel>
                                  <Image Source="Your image" />
                                  <Image Source="Small image" />
                                  </stackpanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

and bind this listbox with your collection of data.

Comment: Hi,Please tell me how to design the screen like as  above screen shot.how to place image inside small image and textblock....how to give item container style for that.

Comment: i am using above code to bind the items and how to design the screen like as above screen shot.